# Macro to paste data from one sheet to blank column in the last populated row of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code, the first part of which works fine, but I cannot get the destination bit for rng2 to work - keep getting a "application-defined or object-defined error".  Wondered if anyone could help with where I am going wrong as I've tried a few different methods (destination being the neatest I know a little about).

```
Sub Assign_TN()

' Assign_TN Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Check sheet")
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open("A Location\TNG Register ongoing.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wbk2.Worksheets("TNG")


'This clears the TN has failed comment in the event the cannot generate Tn macro has been run

ws.Range("A83").ClearContents

' Copy the first set of data from the checksheet and paste into the first blank row of the TNG register

Set Rng = ws.Range("B93:M93")
    Rng.Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

'copy second set of data from checksheet and paste into first blank cell in column 22

Set rng2 = ws.Range("Q93:AM93")
    rng2.Copy
    Destination = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(x1Up).Offset(0)
```

All I need this to do is copy two ranges data into two separate area's of the first unpopulated row in a second sheet.  This in effect generates an acceptance number which is subsequently copied and pasted into the first sheet (this bit of code hasn't been added and works well).

Comment: Look at the syntax of your `rng.copy` line (which is fine) and see if you can see the difference in the `rng2` line(s).

Comment: Why the use of `.Offset(0)` ?

Comment: Also note the typo in `x1Up` which should be `xlUp`. It must be a lower case `XL` not a one `X1`. • I recommend to activate `Option Explicit` to avoid such typos: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've just spent the last hour working on this and amending both sheets to change ranges, to in effect make up one range, but will try the above and see if this works.